# An inequality of graph coloring

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

> Let $G_1=(V,E_1)$ and $G_2=(V,E_2)$ be two graphs with the same vertices. Define a new graph $G=(V,E_1 \cup E_2)$. Prove that $$χ(G)\leqslant χ(G_1)χ(G_2),$$
>   when $χ(G)$ is the coloring number of $G$.

I would appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: The right-hand side is the number of pairs (color from $G_1$, color from $G_2$).

Comment: No. It is the product of x(G1) and x(G2)

Comment: Yes, but I was giving you a hint ;)

Comment: I need a stronger hint, still can't crack that.

Comment: If a vertex has color $c_1$ in $G_1$ and $c_2$ in $G_2$, give it color $(c_1,c_2)$ in $G$.

Comment: Thank you! solved!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chromatic number of union of graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3972807/chromatic-number-of-union-of-graphs)